# Ordering div with flex css

Tags: css, flexbox

We’d like to display 4 divs (from order 1 to order 4) on the left column and 2 divs (order 5 and 6) on the right column BUT the height of the main div can’t be defined. The divs on the right should be 400px. Is there a way to display these columns this way without defining the main div’s height ?

Here's the layout : 
[image]

I'm asking this question because I want my layout to be responsive so if I defined the height of the main div, some divs from the left column will display on the right when I'm resizing the window...

Comment: Post fiddle please.

Comment: Use CSS columns instead. You don't really need flexbox for this.

Comment: I do need flex because the order of the divs will change on mobile version